# Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id for instruction

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, solana-test-validator

i deployed a solana native program on the local test validator and writing a small python script to test it, my python script that's causing the error

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from spl.token.client import Token

# this is my test wallet
wallet = Keypair.from_secret("private key")

client = Client("http://localhost:8899")

token = Token.create_mint(client, wallet, wallet.public_key, 9, program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, freeze_authority=wallet.public_key)
token_account = token.create_associated_token_account(wallet.public_key, skip_confirmation=True)
```

and well, the issue is when creating a token_account, i get an error saying

```
solana.rpc.core.RPCException: SendTransactionPreflightFailureMessage { message: "Transaction
simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction", 
data: RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: 
Some(Tagged(InstructionError(TransactionErrorInstructionError((0, 
Fieldless(IncorrectProgramId)))))), logs: Some(["Program 
ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]", "Program log: Create", "Program 
TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log: Instruction: 
GetAccountDataSize", "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId", "Program 
TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 194486 compute units", "Program 
TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction", 
"Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 6398 of 200000 compute 
units", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id 
for instruction"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None } }
```

and i tried the changing the program to SYS_PROGRAM_ID just to make sure, no luck, what may i do to solve this one?

Answer (score 2):

**Update your validator**. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on a fresh test validator using version 1.14.10 of the Solana CLI.  Here's the full script that I ran:

```
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from spl.token.client import Token
from spl.token.constants import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

# this is my test wallet
wallet = Keypair.generate()

client = Client("http://localhost:8899", Confirmed)
resp = client.request_airdrop(wallet.public_key, 1_000_000_000, Confirmed)
client.confirm_transaction(resp.value, Confirmed)
resp = client.get_balance(wallet.public_key, commitment=Confirmed)

token = Token.create_mint(client, wallet, wallet.public_key, 9, program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, freeze_authority=wallet.public_key)
token_account = token.create_associated_token_account(wallet.public_key, skip_confirmation=True)
```

It might be that `create_associated_token_account` is happening before the mint is actually created, or the test ledger has been busted by something.